# Convert SQL "Concat" to Activerecord

Tags: mysql, sql, ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

I have a SQL query like this:

```
select * from clients where 'Ed Sheeran' like Concat(Concat('%',first_name),'%') 
or 'Ed Sheeran' like Concat(Concat('%',last_name),'%')
```

I want to convert my query to active record.

I'd attempted to convert it:

```
Client.joins(:cases).where(''Ed Sheeran' LIKE CONCAT(CONCAT('%'first_name, )'%')' OR 'Ed Sheeran' LIKE CONCAT(CONCAT('%'last_name, )'%')')
```

but I've got this result:

```
Incorrect parameter count in the call to native function 'CONCAT': SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `clients` INNER JOIN `cases` ON `cases`.`client_id` = `clients`.`id` AND `cases`.`deleted_at` IS NULL WHERE `clients`.`deleted_at` IS NULL AND ('%Ed Sheeran%' LIKE CONCAT(CONCAT()):
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I may be wrong, but it looks to me that you can easily get rid of the double concat if you rewrite the query to avoid YODA-style from

```
select * from clients where 'Ed Sheeran' like Concat(Concat('%',first_name),'%') 
or 'Ed Sheeran' like Concat(Concat('%',last_name),'%')
```

to

```
SELECT * 
FROM clients 
WHERE 
    first_name LIKE "%Ed Sheeran%" OR
    last_name LIKE "%Ed Sheeran%"
```

and in ActiveRecord

```
Client.joins(:cases).where("first_name LIKE :query OR last_name LIKE :query", query: "%Ed Sheeran%")
```

if that's not the case, this is the other query.

```
Client.joins(:cases).where("'Ed Sheeran' LIKE CONCAT(CONCAT('%', first_name), '%') OR 'Ed Sheeran' LIKE CONCAT(CONCAT('%', last_name), '%')")
```

Your query was missing some comma separation.

Comment: Oh yeah! I have a missing comma separation. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you want to use like this ?

```
query = 'Ed Sheeran'

Client.where("first_name LIKE :query OR last_name LIKE :query", query: "%#{query}%")
```